# Can i set listView's gravity to bottom in Drawer Layout?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, slidingmenu, drawerlayout

I want to do like that

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. A solid background is used for contrast
     with the content view. -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and java code

```
  new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
            ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.BOTTOM)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.BOTTOM);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.BOTTOM);
                }
            }
            return false;
            }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}
```

It is giving the error

Fatal Exception - the drawer is not sliding drawer

Is it possible to set gravity to bottom ?

And How can i use fragments instead of listview. I want to switch between fragments by pressing buttons

Can we remove action bar and use buttons to populate drawer ?

i want to switch between menus using buttons.

Thanks to all...

Comment: do want drawer to come from bottom of the screen??

Comment: Because slidingDrawer Did not worked for me as i want!